# How do I restore entire project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, revision-history, working-copy

I was playing around with my project and accidentally clicked something that deleted my entire project except for the JAR files. I restored most of the project from my local history. However, some files are still missing(I think it is only the web.xml but I am not very sure). My question is that, is there any way I can restore my entire project to the way it was 20 mins back? I did make an initial commit on SVN but for some reason that doesn't show up either.
Thanks

Comment: If you use a Mac, you might be able to retrieve it from Time Machine.

Comment: That said, if you only did 20 minutes of work it might be faster to just redo it.

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did the initial commit, then you can [`svn checkout`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) the working copy again and start over.

Apache Subversion does not track uncommitted changes, so your uncomitted work is not recoverable from the version-control.

Comment: Hi, That is what I did and restored the whole project:). Thanks